# How do I write to a file every [insert interval here]?

Tags: java, file-io

I know how to write to a file in Java. My question is based around when I should release resources.

If I had a thread which writes the contents of an `ArrayList` to a file every 2 minutes, how do I deal with the resources for file handling. The file could be read by another program at any point.

Every time I write to a file, do I close the `FileOutputStream` and `PrintWriter` after each iteration of the loop, or is it more efficient to keep them open and close them when the thread terminates. Or does this lock the file so it can't be read by another program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should close the file streams when you are finished, and reopen them on your next write (2 minutes is a long enough gap that the overhead of opening / closing is insignficant).

In order to ensure that other programs or threads do not access the file while you are writing, then you should lock it by getting the FileChannel and invoking the lock() method.

E.g.

```
FileLock lock;
FileChannel channel;
try
{
  channel = myOutputStream.getChannel();
  lock = channel.lock(); // This is a blocking lock, also consider tryLock()
  // ... write your data
} catch (Exception e)
{

} finally
{
  lock.release();
  channel.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Swing timer:

```
import javax.swing.Timer;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000 * 60 * 2, new ActionListener() {
        public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            // Put your file-writing code in here.
            // Yes, you should close the file.
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Closing the file lets other applications access the file. It will also make your code throw a `FileNotFoundException` if the file is moved/renamed/deleted in between runs, which would be easier to understand than an `IOException`.

For more information on File IO: see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html).

For more information on Swing Timers, see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

WC

Comment: The code is irrelevant, but you did answer my question. I must close the file to let other applications access it and reopen it whenever I want to write to it.

Comment: Why use a swing timer instead of a java.util.Timer?  Outside of UI code, java.util.Timer would be preferred, I would think.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, it locks files that are open.
On Linux/Unix, you can still open files that are open (e.g. tail'ing log files).